# Will MSIH61m-p20(g3) supports nvidea gt 1030?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card, blender, solidworks

there! I'm looking to buy a new GPU for blender 2.8 ( I'm new to the blender) currently, I have no graphic card plugged to my desktop. After looking around I found a graphic card which is within my budget (Nvidia GT 1030) my question is whether it is supported by blender 2.8? also to my motherboard which is **MSI H61M-p20(g3) **. I tried online but I think I'm not getting what I'm looking for
would be great if you people help me our thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will work with this motherboard.

It's a low-end GPU though, it likely won't be sufficient for your needs. If your budget is limited, consider buying a used graphics card.